# How can I check the loss of a model at a specific epoch in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I was training a deep learning model ([link)](https://github.com/YisenWang/MART) and it was printing the loss and robustness stats after each epoch, but when it was done executing the terminal closed so I could not see the stats (I am using ssh+screen function so that is normal). I did 120 epochs and after training a folder called `log` was generated which contains `train_stats.npy` and a folder called `resnet` (the training code was in `train_resnet.py`) was generated and it contains 2 files for each epoch, for example:

```
model-res-epoch93.pt   opt-res-checkpoint_epoch93.tar
model-res-epoch94.pt   opt-res-checkpoint_epoch94.tar
model-res-epoch95.pt   opt-res-checkpoint_epoch95.tar
model-res-epoch96.pt   opt-res-checkpoint_epoch96.tar
model-res-epoch97.pt   opt-res-checkpoint_epoch97.tar
model-res-epoch98.pt   opt-res-checkpoint_epoch98.tar
model-res-epoch99.pt   opt-res-checkpoint_epoch99.tar
model-res-epoch9.pt    opt-res-checkpoint_epoch9.tar
```

Is there any way I could use any of these files to get back the stats at a specific epoch? Or do I have to repeat the training?

Answer (score 0):

Those files are likely to only contain the model states and training checkpoints. If you saved your loss and metrics inside the checkpoint archives then you will be able to retrieve this information. Else this information is simply not accessible anymore.
What are you saving inside the `.tar` archives?

Comment: I think (code is not mine and I am getting familiar with it)the `.tar` archive has the weights and biases as it is saved using the following line ` torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(),
                       os.path.join(model_dir, 'opt-res-checkpoint_epoch{}.tar'.format(epoch)))`

Comment: Ok so no, it contains the optimizer's state, not the model. Therefore you won't be able to retrieve the loss from these files. A retraining will be required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the validation loss at the end of an epoch, you load the model, set it into inference mode and compute the loss for the validation set.

The training loss reported at the end of an epoch, however, is usually the sum (or the average per training item) of all the losses encountered during the training epoch, not the loss for the full training data at the end of the epoch. Since the model parameters change during training, this is different to calculating the loss for the model obtained at the end of the epoch. Unless your tar files contain model checkpoints from after each optimiser step, you will have to train the models again. If you are only interested in training losses from, say epoch 5 onward, you could try to continue training from the previous checkpoint but setting the optimiser and learning rate scheduler into the correct state can be difficult.